# Prompt for new SQL Server credentials in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, office365

I was creating a SQL query in excel via Data > Get Data > From Database > From SQL Server Database button. During the creation, I accidently attempted to create the source using windows authentication which will not work as I need to use SQL authentication and of course resulted in the expected error. When I try recreating the same connection to the same server it will not prompt any more for credential after adding the DB and Command and must be using the old credentials.

I tried creating a new workbook and it still will not prompt for new credentials.

I was able to successfully link another server which prompted for credentials but no longer will for the server in question.

Is there a file or location in Excel that is storing these credentials that I can remove them from? The troubled server/connection does not appear under the query/connection list in the workbook.

Any help is appreciated!

This is the error I receive and knew would occur when using the wrong credentials: *Details: "Microsoft SQL: The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find where I update these settings:

In Excel, go to **Data > Queries and Connections**

Hover over the specific query in questions and click "**Edit**" which will open in "*Power Query Editor*".

Click "**Data Source Settings**" in the menu bar. Click "**Edit Permissions**" on the specific connection and adjust the authentication details from there.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, found the path to edit credentials for connections/queries that were never successful and therefore won't show up in "Queries & Connections" tab:
Data Tab > Get Data > Data Source Settings > Select "Global Permissions" at the top > Find the failed server connection & click "Edit Permissions".